# in Flutter Web, How to get the downloadURL WITH the revokable token?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I know how to get the "downloadURL with token" by "firebase_storage" package in mobile environment. It is a full URL that can download the file directly by any browser.

However, 'firebase_storage' package cannot be used in flutter web.
The firebase storage function in flutter web is handled by "firebase" package.

in "firebase" package, use getDownloadURL() method can get the Uri, for example:

```
final Uri downloadUrl =
    await (await _uploadTask.future).ref.getDownloadURL();
```

This "Uri" is just the reference location of the file in firebase Storage. It does not contain the token for downloading the file.

Anyone knows how to get the download token in "firebase" package for flutter web?

Thank you.

Comment: So you're saying the URL you get doesn't work - it doesn't download the file that was uploaded?  It should have the download token embedded in it.

Comment: Yes, the URL in "firebase" package does not have the download token embedded in it. It is just "/v0/b/xxxxx.appspot.com/o/xxxxxx.pdf".
It does not contain the download token as "firebase_storage" package.

If I use "firebase_storage" package, the download link will look this "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxxxx.appspot.com/o/jxxxxx.pdf?alt=media&token=a12345eb-1234-4a53-1234-b4fd9d767a61"

However, flutter web cannot use "firebase_storage" package.